# Order sql query before executing case statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to calculate the balance for a chart that i need to create however i've reached a problem where the data is not ordered after date and if i order it by date it will do it after i have calculated the balance and therefor the balance is still wrong. How can i calculate the balance after the query is ordered by that date?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/374b9/6

test data:

```
CREATE TABLE betting 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key,
     date DATETIME, 
     odds varchar(20),
     status varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO betting
(id, date, odds, status)
VALUES
('1', '2015-02-08 20:27:44', '1.70', 'wrong'),
('2', '2015-02-08 13:22:17', '3.05', 'correct'),
('3', '2015-02-09 16:40:45', '2.20', 'correct'),
('4', '2015-02-10 13:58:24', '1.33', 'correct'),
('5', '2015-02-12 11:37:51', '1.35', 'correct'),
('6', '2015-02-12 10:24:13', '1.38', 'correct');


SET @balance = 0;
SELECT date, odds, status, CASE WHEN status =  'wrong'
            THEN @balance := @balance -100
            ELSE @balance := @balance + ( odds * 100 - 100 ) 
            END as balance
from betting
```

Desired balance

```
205
105
225
258
293
331
```

i've created a SQLFiddle for making it easier.

---

**EXTRA INFO**

Since there is some confusion i've decided to add the real query which is a bit longer due to the fact it is wordpress.

```
    SET @balance = 0;
     SELECT odds.meta_value AS odds, stat.meta_value AS stats, posts.post_date, 
        CASE WHEN stat.meta_value =  'wrong'
        THEN @balance := @balance -100
        ELSE @balance := @balance + ( odds.meta_value * 100 - 100 ) 
        END as balance
                FROM wp_t3a673_posts posts
                LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_postmeta stat ON posts.ID = stat.post_id
                AND stat.meta_key =  'status'
                LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_postmeta odds ON posts.ID = odds.post_id
                AND odds.meta_key =  'odds'
                LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_term_relationships tr ON posts.ID = tr.object_id
                LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_term_taxonomy t ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id
                WHERE (
                stat.meta_value =  'correct'
                OR stat.meta_value =  'wrong'
                )
                AND posts.post_status =  'publish'
                AND t.taxonomy =  'category'
                AND (
                t.term_id =4
                OR t.term_id =5
                OR t.term_id =6
                )
        ORDER BY posts.post_date
```

The result of this is below. Here you can clearly see that the first balance is not correct: it should be -100, but returns 105 and that is due to the fact that it orders after the balance is calculated:

[image]

And if i just -100 either way if it is wrong or correct you can even clearly see the issue

[image]

Comment: Isn't id 2 meant to be after id 1?

Comment: +1 for providing a fiddle straight away. But what would be the actual desired result here, can you show that? I tried putting an outer SELECT around our query and ordering by date in that, but this yields different values for balance. Can you explain some more what that value is supposed to represent?

Comment: the first two rows of your snapshot are the opposite of the ones in your dataset. 1.70 at 13:22 and 3.05 at 20:27. Which one do we have to use?

Comment: i just made a set of dataset i would myself be able to apply it to the correct one, but since i had trouble explaining myself, i decided to add the correct one. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably, that because of joins, the variables are evaluated at an earlier stage.

Try to embed the main query forcing mysql to evaluate the variables in the end:

```
SET @balance = 0;
 SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN stats =  'wrong'
    THEN @balance := @balance -100
    ELSE @balance := @balance + ( odds * 100 - 100 ) 
    END as balance
    FROM (SELECT odds.meta_value AS odds, stat.meta_value AS stats, posts.post_date
            FROM wp_t3a673_posts posts
            LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_postmeta stat ON posts.ID = stat.post_id
            AND stat.meta_key =  'status'
            LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_postmeta odds ON posts.ID = odds.post_id
            AND odds.meta_key =  'odds'
            LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_term_relationships tr ON posts.ID = tr.object_id
            LEFT JOIN wp_t3a673_term_taxonomy t ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id
            WHERE (
            stat.meta_value =  'correct'
            OR stat.meta_value =  'wrong'
            )
            AND posts.post_status =  'publish'
            AND t.taxonomy =  'category'
            AND (
            t.term_id =4
            OR t.term_id =5
            OR t.term_id =6
            )
    ORDER BY posts.post_date
    ) tt
```

Comment: I edited this answer based on the extra info, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it... Is it that?

```
  SET @balance:=0;
  SELECT date, odds, status,
      @balance:=@balance+IF(status='wrong', 0, odds*100)-100 as balance
  FROM betting
  ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: Yes but it will calculate the balance and then after order by date and then the numbers will be in wrong order

Comment: but it matches the desired balance in your latest edition. i don't understand your problem...

Comment: I've added info under the bold text "EXTRA INFO"